# Haskell - using getOpt to parse arguments, why does ReqArg take multiple Arguments?

Tags: haskell, getopt

I got an argument parser working using `getOpt` which is great, but I do have one question. When using  `ReqArg` in an option like:

```
Option ['c'] ["config"] (ReqArg (\f opts -> opts { configFile = f }) "FILE")
                     "use a custom configuration file"
```

what does it use that second argument for (in this case, `"FILE"`)?  I have not experienced any kind of difference in behavior when specifying another string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's for the auto-generated usage message. Same with OptArg. Run `usageInfo` on your OptDescr list and see what comes back.